# How to get bootstrap 4 flex table that does not spread over 100% of the width of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In the following example, I want to format the divs like a table, but I don't want to spread the text over 100% of the width of the page. I want the columns to be as close to each other so it will read as normal text. For the example below I want to display it as:

```
aaa   bb   ccc ddd 
aaaaa bbbb c   dd
```

When I try to use Bootstrap 4's `.row` and `.col` I get the table formatting I want, but then the table spreads the text over 100% of the width of the page. How can I get the above formatting?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="font-family: Consolas;">
   <div class="d-flex p-2">
      <div>aaa&nbsp;</div>
      <div>bb&nbsp;</div>
      <div>ccc&nbsp;</div>
      <div>ddd&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
   <div class="d-flex p-2">
      <div>aaaaa&nbsp;</div>
      <div>bbbb&nbsp;</div>
      <div>c&nbsp;</div>
      <div>dd&nbsp;</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I realize using a normal `table` without the CSS of Bootstrap might do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the behavior of a `<table>`, that's what you should use.
Bootstrap only styles `<table>`s having the class of `table`, to allow using `<table>`s for any other purpose:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>aaa&nbsp;</td>
      <td>bb&nbsp;</td>
      <td>ccc&nbsp;</td>
      <td>ddd&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaaa&nbsp;</td>
      <td>bbbb&nbsp;</td>
      <td>c&nbsp;</td>
      <td>dd&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To have the Bootstrap's `<table>` specific styling ***and*** make the table **not stretch** the entire width of its parent you can give the table `width: auto`:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table" style="width: auto">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>aaa&nbsp;</td>
      <td>bb&nbsp;</td>
      <td>ccc&nbsp;</td>
      <td>ddd&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaaa&nbsp;</td>
      <td>bbbb&nbsp;</td>
      <td>c&nbsp;</td>
      <td>dd&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can also rely on Bootstrap's grid system to limit the width of the `<table>` or of its parent.